# How to return error message in Yup require method using function instead of just passing the string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I want to add some expressions before throwing error message.

Below is the example code that I want to implement.

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required(() => "error message") 
});
```

Instead of just passing a string like this

```
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
    name: yup.string().required("error message") 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to pass in a function using Yup test method. You just have to be sure to createError and return that to yup once created.

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string()
    .string()
    .required()
    .test("name validation fn", "Name Validation Error", function (value) { // Use function
     const customError = myCustomErrorFn(value);
     return this.createError({message: customError });
    })
});
```

see Yup [validation docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#validation-tests)